# Assigning certain commands to users

Tags: git, ubuntu, command, sudoers

I want to only allow the "git" userto be able to run git commands, I edited my sudoers file using `sudo visudo` and added

```
# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias GIT_CMDS = /usr/bin/git

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
git ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: GIT_CMDS
```

When I then try to run git commands from the git user I get an error saying I do not have the correct access rights.
How can I fix this?

Comment: If you changed the groups that the user is associated with, did you logout and log back in again so the new groups are applied?

Comment: @jdv yup, after I did the edit with the root user I then did su into the git user

Comment: Wait. Your question doesn't match what you are trying to do. Do you want only the git _user_ or members of the the git _group_ to be managed in this way?

Comment: I want the git user to be managed in this way

Comment: You should change the question. You say "usergroup" which is confusing.

Comment: @jdv fixed it :)

Comment: Ok, since `/usr/bin/git` is otherwise available to all, what have you done to restrict access?

Comment: Good reference: https://superuser.com/q/735172/609232

Comment: No what I want to do is to only allow the git user to run git commands so I added the lines above to the sudoers file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"access right" might be different from "command execution right"

git could still be able to run git commands, but might not be able to update a folder not owned by git/git group.

That is why you have questions like "[Allow User 'git' to run 'git pull' as '`www-data`' via sudo](https://serverfault.com/a/269363/783)", in order to allow

```
 sudo -u www-data git <a command>
```

In your case, since you have specified `(ALL)`, check if your access error goes aways with the proper `sudo -u <auser>` when you run commands as `git` in a folder not owned by `git`.